Is there a to detect when somone is napping using wearable/portable devices?
If Someone unwantedly naps during the day. Is there any feasible way to detect them and send out an alert to wake him up?
Regarding The specifics: I meant if a student just unwantedly napped on his desk; could there be an wearable device that detects that within a small time frame (like 5-10)m and send an alert to wake him up? It just has to be practical; so 'technical' stuff costing millions is not an option

Are you referring to equipment such as systems in cars that monitor the driver for alertness? They've been around for a while, but this doesn't seem terribly on-topic here. Could you add some details about the specifics of what you're looking for. We're expected to show our understanding of a topic within a question, only then can we determine how to answer.

@JiminyCricket. Did it! Basically like an wearable kinda device that doesn't cost millions for students and that sort

Can anyone help

So, you're looking for a hardware recommendation, not anything to do with academic psychology? There are no sites on the network where products can be recommended, except [hardwarerecs.se] where this would be off-topic as not about computer hardware. Wearable tech doesn't have a site here yet. Best you could do is go to our [arduino.se] site and gain enough reputation to talk to someone in the chat rooms there and ask their advice - else ask off-network. (Quora/reddit maybe??)
